# Cómo conectar el SQL Developer a la base de datos Oracle 21c?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, networking, oracle-19c

[image: SQL Developer Error]

Cuando instalé la base de datos Oracle 21c, ésta no me creó automáticamente los archivos tnsnames.ora ni listeners.ora.
Probé creando un listener "LISTENER1" con la herramienta que trae pero no se como utilizarlo y aún así no me creó los archivos correspondientes en la carpeta network de la base de datos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y la base esta levantada y escuchando en ese puerto?

Comment: 1522 suena a un puerto bien inusual para una instancia por defecto. Y pues, el error es de red, no hay listener en localhost puerto 1522. Revisa tu instancia. Tampoco sabemos qué hiciste con la herramienta que trae (que son varias y no sabemos cuál usaste...). Sé más específico por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final desinstalé y volví a instalar siguiendo los pasos en
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYleroLay5E&list=LL5mVVsrAc9rtp3xBJTJUAow

Me fije cual era mi hostname para el string de conección y en el sql developer en ves de SID puse nombre de servicio.

Comment: Entonces la desinstalación/instalación no tenía nada que ver.